# Greystripe and proguard

Tags: android, netbeans, proguard

So we have reached the last phases of development of our Android game, and it's time to include some obfuscation with Proguard.

Our game is using Greystripe ads, and everything works fine when compiling the debug version, targeting API 7.

But when compiling the release version (with Proguard added in the process), there's a ton of warnings:

```
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.DeviceInfo: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.DeviceInfo: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.DeviceInfo: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.DeviceInfo: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.DeviceInfo: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.DeviceInfo: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.DeviceInfo: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.DeviceInfo: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.DeviceInfo: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.DeviceInfo: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.DeviceInfo: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.DeviceInfo: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.DeviceInfo: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.GSFullscreenActivity: can't find referenced class android.hardware.Camera$CameraInfo
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.GSFullscreenActivity: can't find referenced class android.hardware.Camera$CameraInfo
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.GSFullscreenActivity: can't find referenced method 'void getCameraInfo(int,android.hardware.Camera$CameraInfo)' in class android.hardware.Camera
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.GSFullscreenActivity: can't find referenced method 'int getNumberOfCameras()' in class android.hardware.Camera
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.GSFullscreenActivity: can't find referenced method 'android.hardware.Camera open(int)' in class android.hardware.Camera
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.GSFullscreenActivity: can't find referenced method 'void setDisplayOrientation(int)' in class android.hardware.Camera
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.GSFullscreenActivity: can't find referenced class android.hardware.Camera$CameraInfo
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.GSFullscreenActivity: can't find referenced method 'void setLayerType(int,android.graphics.Paint)' in class com.greystripe.sdk.aa
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.a: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.a: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.ah: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.aj: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.aj: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.aj: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.as: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.as: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.as: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.as: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.as: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.at: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.at: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.bd: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.be: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.be: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.be: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.be: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.be: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.be: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.bh: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.bh: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.bl: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.bl: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.bl: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.bl: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.bl: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.m: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.m: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.m: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.m: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.m: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.m: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.m: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.m: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.m: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.s: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.s: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.w: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.w: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.w: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.w: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.w: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.w: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.w: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.w: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.w: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: com.greystripe.sdk.w: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
Warning: there were 64 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
     You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
Warning: there were 5 unresolved references to program class members.
     Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
     You may need to recompile them and try again.
     Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
     '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
```

So obviously I began trying a lot of different variations of `-keep class` and `-keep public class` etc, without any effect. Then I began Googling a lot, and found a ton of forum posts where people had the somewhat same issue, and I tried all the suggestions people replied. Still no change.

Then I took a look in android.jar and found out that `android.webkit.JavascriptInterface` wasn't introduced before API 17, and then it makes sense of course. Because I'm targeting API 7, so naturally there's no `android.webkit.JavascriptInterface` available.

But I don't want to target API 17 just because of ads, and I'm pretty sure I shouldn't have to either.

Logically I think I should be able to just `-dontwarn`, but doing this results in an App that crashes on load.

I make sure of course that I put `-libraryjars /path/to/libs/greystripe-android-sdk-2.3.0.jar` and also `/path/to/android.jar`

Does anyone have any clue about this? How do I obfuscate my app, while leaving the greystripe-sdk jar alone?

Comment: I should add, that the crash that happens when using `-dontwarn` is indeed a NullPointer Exception in the Greystripe classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProGuard prints these warnings right after having read the input, so `-keep` options won't help. You should build against API 17, so ProGuard can find all the classes that it needs to analyze and process your application. You can still specify different targets in your AndroidManifest.xml.

If you are using the standard Ant/Eclipse/Gradle builds, you should not specify `-libraryjars`, since those builds already do that for you.

Comment: Wow, a reply from the man himself. Thanks! I was recommended by another guy to target API 17 too, though for other reasons. So that's probably what I'll end up doing. For now though, I actually managed to get it working with a `-dontwarn` parameter. It compiles and runs without errors. The runtime log does show a warning though, and it'll be interesting to see if that'll go away when/if targeting API 17.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your ProGuard file:

`-keep class com.greystripe.** { *; }`

That should remove the warnings and allow the Greystripe SDK to function as intended.

If for some reason that line does not fix it, try this:

`-keep class com.greystripe.** { *; }`

`-keepclassmembers class com.greystripe.** { public *; }`

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't have time to test this at the moment (have a bunch of other stuff I have to do), I want to write it here while it's still fresh in my mind. Then we'll see if it turns out to be the solution later.

Important thing to keep in mind: targetSdkVersion is not the same as build version.

In this case with Greystripe classes, where they obviously tests for the existence of certain Android classes that is only available since API 17, you should set your build target to API 17. This mean that you'll compile using the classes available in API 17. Proguard should therefor not give the warnings.

In your AndroidManifest.xml file though, you don't necessarily have to put targetSdkVersion="17". You can set it to whatever target you wish. (Although since ICS and the menu-button issue, it's recommended to always target API 14 or above).

So optimal settings (in theory, will have to test later) right now, is to set

build target = API 17 - to avoid Proguard warnings, because Greystripe API refers to classes in API 17
sdkTargetVersion >= 14 - because of compatibility issues. Set it to the API version you're able to test on
minTargetVersion = 7 (if your app will run on API 7) - because Greystripe API should run on API 7 according to the docs

Then everything should work.

More (semi) related reading:
http://simonvt.net/2012/02/07/what-api-level-should-i-target/
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH